# How do I use exportgraphics() to export both a regular figure and UI Text that I have added to it?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am writing a script that automatically takes data from a spreadsheet (generated in a different script) and generates several plots using parameters contained therein and the filename(s) of the spreadsheet(s) involved. On two of the six plots that it generates, I am plotting data for white and black pixels from binarized images together. Previously, when plotting only one type of data at a time, I have had success in inserting a legend between the subtitle of the plot and the plot itself by adding whitespace below the subtitle and using lgd.Position() arguments to put the subtitle in the correct place.

However, I have been trying to add a notation on the side of the horizontally-orientated legend to indicate whether the symbols on that row corresponded to black or white pixels, as in:

Title (centered)
Subtitle (centered)
{UI} White: {Legend} [symbol] [description] [symbol] [description] [symbol] [description] (all centered)
{UI} Black: {Legend} [symbol] [description] [symbol] [description] [symbol] [description] (all centered)

The trouble is, when I try this, the legend and ui text disappear entirely and I get the warning upon export: "Warning: UI Components will not be included in the output."

What about ui objects and exportgraphics() do I not understand? How can I make this work? Does it have anything to do with the fact that all of the plotting goes on in a function instead of in the main script?

Thus far I have tried orienting the position of the legend first, then basing the position of the ui text from the legend, but that gave the same result as vice versa. I also tried using a uifigure() instead of a normal one, since I thought maybe that would make it compatible with the ui text, but it backfired and gave blank graphics objects instead. I've also researched other types of objects I can use, but uicontrol() seems to be the only command that allows me to add .Position based text outside of a plot, but within a figure.

Images of my code:

[Calling the plotting function and exporting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUOXV.png)
[Relevant Plot Creation in plotting function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/froDf.png)
[Adding labels to plot in plotting function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoLIP.png)
Here, the first block of code produced the successful image without the ui text, and the second is the code that does not work properly:
[Adding legend and text in plotting function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Fwf.png)
[Change plot colors depending on color scheme within plotting function (may not be relevant)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2YJv.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Use [Annotation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html). You should be able to place a text box anywhere you want with some effort. That said I sometimes use [tiledlayout](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiledlayout.html) and a separate tile/subplot just to do annotations.

Comment: You are a lifesaver! I changed "uicontrol" to "annotation", made a few tweaks, and now my code runs and exports fine! Thank you!